# Stuck with saving genreated blob with video data

Tags: javascript, blob

Trying to save the blob generated from webcam stream. Here is the code.
Here is the project: http://a5w.org/prog/vimeo/2/  (FF compatible)

It does generate the blob with video data but for a strange reason I cannot save it. I tried to generate a simple blob (var blob = new Blob(['body { color: red; }'], {type: 'text/css'});) and it was saved without any problems but the video doesn't want to be saved for some reason =(
This is Mediastream Recorder : https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/MediaStreamRecorder.js"> </script>

<body>

<script>
var mediaConstraints = {
    audio: !!navigator.mozGetUserMedia, // don't forget audio!
    video: true                         // don't forget video!
};

navigator.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints, onMediaSuccess, onMediaError);

function onMediaSuccess(stream) {
    var mediaRecorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.mimeType = 'video/webm';
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (blob) {
        // POST/PUT "Blob" using FormData/XHR2

        var fileType = 'video'; // or "audio"
        var fileName = 'ABCDEF.webm';  // or "wav" or "ogg"

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append(fileType + '-filename', fileName);
        formData.append(fileType + '-blob', mediaConstraints);

        xhr('./save.php', formData, function (fileURL) {
            window.open(fileURL);
        });

        function xhr(url, data, callback) {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                    callback(location.href + request.responseText);
                }
            };
            request.open('POST', url);
            request.send(data);
        }   

     var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
     document.write('<a href="' + blobURL + '">' + blobURL + '</a>');
    };
    mediaRecorder.start(3000);
}

function onMediaError(e) {
    console.error('media error', e);
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

No errors, uploads folder is 777 (and I was able to save a dummy blob object)

PHP file:

```
foreach(array('video', 'audio') as $type) {
   if (isset($_FILES["${type}-blob"])) {

        $fileName = $_POST["${type}-filename"];
        $uploadDirectory = "uploads/$fileName";

        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["${type}-blob"]["tmp_name"], $uploadDirectory)) {
            echo("problem moving uploaded file");
        }

        echo($uploadDirectory);
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'no files in FILES';

    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second attribute of `formData.append(fileType + '-blob', )`  be `blob` instead of  `mediaConstraints` ?

Comment: oh,, yes.. it should. Initially it was so. Unfortunately it doesn't work (I've just checked once again) with the original code either. But  -thank you very much. I ahve forgotten to bring the initial code back for thsi line, indeed.

Comment: and can we assume your php is exactly the same as the one in the MSRecorder examples

Comment: =)
yes, it is
I have added the code to the question above. Thank you for your time Kaiido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with the start method of the MediaRecorder Plugin :

The argument (here `3000`) that you place in is actually an interval for `start()` to fire.

If you place a `this.stop();` into the `mediaRecorder.ondataavailable` handler, you server will have the time to write the file before you ask it to do it again on the next interval.

Or you may also want to increment the filename to save multiple files.

```
var mediaConstraints = {
    audio: !!navigator.mozGetUserMedia, // don't forget audio!
    video: true                         // don't forget video!
};

navigator.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints, onMediaSuccess, onMediaError);

function onMediaSuccess(stream) {

    // var i = 0;
    var mediaRecorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.mimeType = 'video/webm';
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (blob) {
        // POST/PUT "Blob" using FormData/XHR2

        this.stop(); // stop the recorder

        var fileType = 'video'; // or "audio"
        var fileName = 'ABCDEF.webm';  // or 'ABCDEF'+ i++ +'.webm'

        var formData = new FormData();

        ...
```

Apparently, you will also need to remove the `document.write('<a href="' + blobURL + '">' + blobURL + '</a>');` for the request to the server completes.

Comment: Thnaks man! Tried your code. Initially - no result.decided to add one weird thing - alert(blob); before returning the video URL
for a strange reason - it does work now. first I have the alert message saying what it should: "Object: Blob" BUT...it works now. It uploads the blob as ABCDEF.webm on server
WHY on earth is that so????

Comment: the code here should work, maybe you can try changing `this.stop()`to `mediaRecorder.stop() `. If it does work when you set the alert, it is because it blocks the execution of the script, so the request to your server can complete.

Comment: yea - in fact I tried both  this.stop(); and mediaRecorder.stop():
without the alert it doesn't send anything to the PHP file
please have  a look: 
http://a5w.org/prog/vimeo/2/

Comment: ok...deleted the alert and commented the whole thing with the blob URL generation. again - surprisingly now it works. it does upload the file to the server.

Comment: You mean the document.write() part ? Actually I had removed it too

Comment: ah! I just got your ... like "and all the rest of the code is the same"
Thanks for your help man! It does have bugs but that's what I will be able to deal with. I appreciate your help!